# Я ищу Место под шашлыки или для шашлыков

Tags: предлоги

Прошу проверить правильность построения фразы

Answer (score 0):

Зависит от контекста.
*Ищу место под шашлыки.* Это если имеется в виду, что Вы ищете место для **постоянной** готовки шашлыков, или маринования мяса. Шашлыки в данном случае не готовый продукт.
*Ищу место для шашлыков на столе.* В смысле куда их положить, чтобы и стол не испачкать и едокам было удобно их доставать. То есть место в данном случае **временное** и в следующий раз может быть другим. Шашлыки в данном случае готовый продукт.